# cant write away ouput using LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to write away a output of all the original id and what they were updated to but it's failing and I can't figure out why. Any assistance most welcome.

```
declare
  v_ids varchar2(4000); 

begin

--Update tiemline

update time_line tl
set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
where tl.limit_template IN 
(select tl.limit_template from base_timeline_section bbts,
          base_timeline_org bts,
          trmt_timeline tl              
where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720'
);
returning listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group (order by 
tl.limit_template) tl.limit_template
into v_ids;
 dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');

end;
```

i get a ORA-06550 error, encountered LISTAGG when expecting one of the following :=.(@%;
The symbol ":="was substituted for "LISTAGG" to continue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
update time_line tl
   set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
 where tl.limit_template IN
       (select tl.limit_template
          from base_timeline_section bbts,
               base_timeline_org     bts,
               trmt_timeline         tl
         where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
           and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
           and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720')
    returning listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group 
                     (order by tl.limit_template) into v_ids;
```

By using `RETURNING INTO` clause , we are able to return even concatenated multiple columns.

Comment: thank you,  i seem to be getting a ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long, is there any other way to handle this without not using the listagg?

Comment: thank you it seems to run the statement now, although it;s still not writing anything away to the output dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178')

Comment: thanks this seems to be working, the only issue have now is that it grabs the id after it was updated. I need it to show the orignal id and what it was updated to Updated IDs: LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178,LIM0178 to LIM0178